# Test Discovery of Dynamic Tests in Eclipse Slow

Tags: eclipse, junit5

Having a test class like this

```
public class VerySimpleFactory {
    @TestFactory
    public Stream<? extends DynamicNode> someTests() {
        DynamicContainer container1 = DynamicContainer.dynamicContainer("A",
                Arrays.asList(t("A1"), t("A2"), t("A3"), t("A4"), t("A5")));
        DynamicContainer container2 = DynamicContainer.dynamicContainer("B",
                Arrays.asList(t("B1"), t("B2"), t("B3"), t("B4"), t("B5")));
        DynamicContainer container3 = DynamicContainer.dynamicContainer("C",
                Arrays.asList(t("C1"), t("C2"), t("C3"), t("C4"), t("C5")));
        DynamicContainer container4 = DynamicContainer.dynamicContainer("D",
                Arrays.asList(t("D1"), t("D2"), t("D3"), t("D4"), t("D5")));

        return Arrays.asList(container1, container2, container3, container4).stream();
    }

    @Test
    public void t1() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    @Test
    public void t2() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    public DynamicTest t(String name) {
        return DynamicTest.dynamicTest(name, () -> Thread.sleep(1000));
    }
}
```

the Tests having a `@Test` annotaiton are discovered instantly by JUnit View, but the tests from TestFactory are discoverd at runtime, each after the last test was completely executed. This leads to a changing and "jumping" JUnit view. Also I cannot select a special test I'm interested in to be executed as single test, until all previous tests were executed.

It would be much nicer if all dynamic tests were shown in JUnit view also at beginning of test execution.

If this doesn't happen, is it a problem of JUnit 5, eclipse or my code?

Answer (score 3):

**Dynamic** tests are **dynamic**. Not static.

It is not possible to know before-hand which and how many tests will be generated by `@TestFactory` annotated method ... actually, it may produce tests in an eternal loop.

Copied from https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-dynamic-tests-examples

> `generateRandomNumberOfTests()` implements an Iterator that generates
>   random numbers, a display name generator, and a test executor and then
>   provides all three to `DynamicTest.stream()`. Although the
>   non-deterministic behavior of `generateRandomNumberOfTests()` is of
>   course in conflict with test repeatability and should thus be used
>   with care, it serves to demonstrate the expressiveness and power of
>   dynamic tests.

Comment: OK; as far I understand, it's an junit5 issue, so I took discussion to https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1338

Comment: No. It's not a problem of any component. It is by design and working as intended.

Comment: The flickering is because the Eclipse tree view is not incrementally updating but rebuilding from scratch on every change, losing it's state of being open and having things selected. That is absolutely a bug, now that, with junit 5, the tree structure will in fact be updated.